# How to integrate KeePass and Chrome/Chromium using ChromIPass?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, keepass, add-on

I'm trying to integrate KeePass and Chrome/Chromium after installing ChromIPass when I try to connect to KeePass, It gives the following error:

```
ChromeIPass has been disconnected from KeePassHttp.
Association was unsuccessful
Press the reconnect button to establish a new connection.
```

How can I connect ChromeIPass with KeePass?

Comment: Does opening http://localhost:19455 in chrome show a page?  Does your host file still have 127.0.0.1 associated with localhost? Did you install security related software?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rinzwind. I am not a geek. I can follow simple user friendly instructions and installation.

Comment: You need not be a geek to answer all 3. The 1st is opening a wegpage and the 3rd is a question about software you recently installed. Even the middle one is just a `more /etc/hosts` from commandline to check if it is has a line stating `127.0.0.1       localhost` in it. Nothing geek about it :+

Answer (score 24):

Follow these steps for installing KeePass 2

#### Install KeePass:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start terminal and run following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2 mono-complete
```

#### Install KeePassHttp:

Go to this [link](https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/tree/master/mono) and download "KeePassHttp.dll" and "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

[image: A]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `gksu nautilus` to open Nautilus as root.

[image: B]

Copy both files to: `/usr/lib/keepass2`

#### Install ChromeIPass:

Open Chrome/Chromium and install [ChromeIPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae)

#### Configuration:

Open KeePass, and visit any login page in Chrome/Chromium i.e gmail.com.

Click the KeePass icon in the URL bar and click the "Connect" button.

[image: C]

You should see this dialog box

[image: D]

Enter any name for your browser here and save it. That's It.

Comment: Thanks Basharat Sial, Now it's working. Now, I am going to try it on my android mobile.

Comment: Why the h is this not accepted!?

Comment: Any reason for installing KeePass 2 from some PPA? It's in the main Ubuntu repositories. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/keepass2/

Comment: @user35186 It's still possible to download a compatible version from the history. E.g. for `KeePassHttp.dll`: https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/commits/master/mono/KeePassHttp.dll

Comment: ChromelPass link is dead, I believe along with the project. Here is a discussion of KeePass with plugins on Ubuntu and either browser integration in general and that is more current: "KeePass and Ubuntu 20.04 Setup (with Chrome, Firefox)?" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228389/keepass-and-ubuntu-20-04-setup-with-chrome-firefox