# How to get KeePass to properly work with Chromium?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, chromium, keepass

The [two-channel auto-type obfuscation](http://keepass.info/help/v2/autotype_obfuscation.html) feature of KeePass doesn't work for me with Chromium (on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits). However, it works just fine with Firefox.

Dows anyone know how to fix this?

Textboxes in web forms in Chromium seems to have something special that causes this feature to fail. Only some of the username/password characters are being auto-typed.

This might be related to this: if I select an entry in KeePass and click "Copy User Name", I can paste it fine with Ctrl+V in any textbox in Firefox, but I can't on Chromium. However, text copied using Ctrl+C from a regular text file (say, from gedit), can be pasted fine on both browsers.

What may be wrong?

I wouldn't like to deactive this feature for all the entries in my keepass files as I use them on Windows too and they work just fine there (even on Google Chrome for Windows). This feature gives an appreciated extra security measure against spyware/keyloggers.

Comment: Have you tried ChromIpass? [How to integrate KeyPass and Chrom/Chromium using ChromIPass?](http://askubuntu.com/q/130627/37006)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm  not interested in using two more components (KeePassHttp and ChromIPass) to basically do the same thing as auto-typing (I don't want to setup all that in all the plattforms and browsers I use). Auto-type works perfect with Firefox in Ubuntu, it's just Chromium having problems.

Comment: Can you slow the typing rate in KeePass 2.x? I had missing characters in a Windows 1.x version long ago and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You must add {DELAY=50} at first of keystroke sequence and it will slow down typing rate of all text. This will make typing in Google Chrome or Chromium is correct.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score -2):

The [keepass forum on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/forums/forum/329221/topic/5194875) says this has been "fixed in Chrome 19" (still in beta?).

I think it's [issue 32056](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32056).  I'm downloading an update now to see whether it fixes this problem.

---

**Later:** I'm not finding any version 19 of either Chromium or Chrome. I'm off down the rabbit hole to try to track down a binary.

The current beta for Google Chrome is "Version 21.0.1180.15 beta". This keepass issue is fixed in this version of Chrome. The [Chromium beta download](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel/) (64-bit Debian/Ubuntu) is the same file (same md5 sum).

Comment: This should of been added as comment to original question, not as an answer.